# Emberjs register and inject explanation

Tags: ember.js

Using Ember-Cli, I'm trying to add a register an adapter and then inject it into controllers. I don't understand what values I'm supposed to pass into either function, or why their in that format.

(Following provided by emberjs webpage):

```
App.register('network:main', App.NetworkAdapter);
App.inject('controller', 'network', 'network:main');
```

Specifically, I'm unsure of what this "type:name" format is, nor do I understand how the inject values relate to what is in the register function.

Also, does anybody know what the following error means in relation to the application.inject function?

> "Error while processing route: index Failed to create an instance of
>   'qservice:main'. Most likely an improperly defined class or an invalid
>   module export."

Code:

```
export default {
    name: 'qservice',
    initialize: function(container, application){
      application.register("qservice:main", "qservice", {singleton: true});

      application.inject("controller",'qservice',"qservice:main");
    //application.inject("route",'qservice','adapter:main');
   }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter of the register function should be a factory (or instance if instantiate is set to false).  A factory is something you can call `create` on and it will return an instance.  Singleton is true by default, so there is no need to specify it.

```
 var qservice = Em.Object.extend();
 application.register("qservice:main", qservice);


 var qserviceInstance = Em.Object.create();
 application.register("qservice:main", qserviceInstance, {instantiate:false});
```

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand register, but how are those inject parameters related to what I put in my register function? I keep receiving the error listed above the code snippet.

Comment: inject is (typeToInjectInto, whatToCallIt, whatToInject)